# How can I convert a list of values to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a (unsorted) dictionary, where the keys start at 0.0 and continue with 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and so on. All the values are numbers too. 
I also have a sys.argv input, called 'a', which is a float.
I need a new dictionary, where the keys should be:

```
a
a+0.1
a+0.2
a+0.3
```

... until all values in the original dict are assigned a key. The values should remain the same.
so the final dictionary should be:

```
{a:first item of sorted dict, a+0.1:second item of sorted dict,...}
```

So basically, the keys should be added to the size of float 'a'.

I tried by converting the unsorted dictionary into a sorted list like this:

```
list=[]
for i in sorted(dict.keys()):
list.append(dict[i])
```

Now I have a sorted list of the values of the original dict that I need to assign to the new keys.

Comment: Are the keys always incrementing by `0.1`, and is it possible to have a gap?

Comment: Dictionaries don't have a notion of 'sorted'. You should consider using a list instead.

Comment: It is always 0.1, there is never a gap.

Comment: Then you should definitely use a list.

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, since it's a python key word.

Comment: The key is the position of a car and the value is the bending moment caused by it at this position, so I cannot really seperate the both..

Comment: use a OrderedDict as show by @DanielSanchez or use a list of tuples `[(a,value0),(a+0.1,value1),(a+0.2,value2),...]`

Comment: you can try it with `dict(zip(numbers.keys(),sys.argv[1:]))`.

Comment: with sorted list: `dict(zip(sorted(numbers.keys()),sys.argv[1:]))`

Answer (score 3):

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to a maping of the increment to the keys and the values:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {0.1:1,0.2:2}
>>> d
{0.2: 2, 0.1: 1}
>>> od = OrderedDict(d)
>>> od
OrderedDict([(0.2, 2), (0.1, 1)])
>>> newOrderedDict = OrderedDict(map(lambda (x,y): (x+5, y), od.items()))
>>> newOrderedDict
OrderedDict([(5.2, 2), (5.1, 1)])
```

Mind that orderedDict keeps inserting order not value order, so if you want the value order just sort the mapped list before building the new orderedDict

```
>>> newOrderedDict = OrderedDict(sorted(map(lambda (x,y): (x+5, y), od.items()), key=lambda (x,y):x))
>>> newOrderedDict
OrderedDict([(5.1, 1), (5.2, 2)])
```

Comment: thank you! but somehow the output is not ordered..'a' is added to the keys, but the output is: 5.0:value, 5.5:other value, 9.5:another value and so on.

Comment: I tried to sort it with a method I used before: E = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(newOrderedDict.items())) but it didn't work..

Comment: @user5758559, OrderedDict keeps inserting order, not value order, anyway sorted should work, let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not sorted (in a reproducible way for the user). If your goal is just the same dictionary but with each key incremented by `a`, this would work:

```
>>> data = {0.0: 100, 0.1: 200, 0.2: 300, 0.3: 400}
>>> a = 7
>>> new_data = {key + a: value for key, value in data.items()}
>>> new_data
{7.0: 100, 7.1: 200, 7.2: 300, 7.3: 400}
```

Comment: dict objects are not guaranteed to be ordered by default

Comment: Of course they are not. But I sort them before I create the new dictionary. `new_data` is not sorted but is is a dictionary with the desired key-value pairs.

Comment: He needs it sorted righ?, so the new_data dict is still not sorted because is still a dict, still not guaranteed to be sorted

Comment: *I need a new dictionary, where the keys should be:* Nothing said about being sorted. The new keys are there. Mission accomplished.

Comment: yep, my missunderstood then, apologies

Comment: Actually, no need to sort at all as keys and hence the new keys must be unique.